# Xamarin iOS RemoveObserver AVPlayerItem

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have set up a status observer for AVPlayerItem but I am having trouble removing it.

```
 if(_aPlayer.CurrentItem != null)
 {
      _aPlayer.CurrentItem.RemoveObserver(HandleAction1, "status")
 }

 var aAsset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename("some_sounds.mp3"));
 var aPlayerItem = new AVPlayerItem(audioAsset);

 _aPlayer.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(audioPlayerItem);
 aPlayerItem.AddObserver("status", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew, HandleAction1);
```

getting error "cannot convert method group to nsobject"

Answer (score 0):

`AVPlayerItem.AddObserver` returns an `IDisposable` that you need to keep a reference to.

When you are done with that observable call Dispose on it.

```
var statusObserver = aPlayerItem.AddObserver("status", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.OldNew, HandleAction1);

statusObserver.Dispose();
```

Comment: @jimmyneutron It depends upon where the observable is created, If you use `AVPlayerItem.CurrentItem.AddObserver`, `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver`, etc... you are returned an Observer (`NSObject` type) and that object can be passed to its related  `RemoveObserver()` method on the same object

Comment: Do I need to call _aPlayer.CurrentItem.Dispose() afterwards?   if (_aPlayer.CurrentItem != null)
            {
                _statusObserver.Dispose();
                _aPlayer.CurrentItem.Dispose();
            }